# Tapping on footer section causes above cell selection

Tags: ios

I have a UITableView with 3 dynamic prototype cells. One for header section, another for rows and one for footer section. Each of them with custom dequeu identifier. I put cell views to sections views for customizing in storyboard reason. Cell for rows have segue identifier to detailed view controller. When table view contains 1 row tapping on footer section causes above cell selection and performs segue. Is it a bug or i'm doing something wrong?

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UMShoppingCartFooterCell *footerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Footer"];

    [footerCell.makeOrderButton setColor:NORMAL_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [footerCell.makeOrderButton setColor:DISABLED_COLOR forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [footerCell.makeOrderButton setColor:SELECTED_COLOR forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    return footerCell;

}
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Don't put cells in the header or footer. Just put normal views in them.

Comment: But its working well except this problem. The problem ends when tableview contains 2 or more rows

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewHeaderFooterView was made for this purpose. While it's tempting and easy to just use a cell, you'll get unpredictable behaviour like you are experiencing.